# How can I write the theme “try your hardest at everything you do” in one or two words?

Tags: phrase-requests

For example, I could describe “put others before yourself” as “selflessness”. Or “Do not let fear hold you back” as “courage”.

Comment: To be pedantic, you could describe "Put others before yourself" as a recommendation _to be selfless_.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***diligence***:

> the quality of working carefully and with a lot of effort ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diligence))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diligence) gives a very good synonym (*assiduity*) in its definition of *diligence*:

> steady, earnest, and energetic effort : devoted and painstaking work and application to accomplish an undertaking : ASSIDUITY

See also *[assiduous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assiduous)*.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of  aspects to the OP's request: everything (or always/at all times), a verb meaning *try*, total commitment, and, possibly, consideration for others. With a limit of two words, I'd choose:

> **strive** **wholeheartedly**

I like *strive* because it conveys substantial, prolonged effort with a connotation that always achieving your goal is not possible. One hopes the *utmost sincerity* in *wholeheartedly* includes fairness toward others. After I chose the words, I looked for the collocation in Google books.

**strive** (v.)

> To devote serious effort or energy : ENDEAVOR [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strive)

> To endeavour vigorously, use strenuous effort. OED

**wholeheartedly** (adv.)

> In a completely committed or totally sincere manner. OED

> With the utmost sincerity, enthusiasm, commitment, etc.
> [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wholeheartedly)

---

> How displeased He would be if we refuse to think, work and **strive
> wholeheartedly**, to use the wealth on earth and in firmament that has
> already been given, but instead sit on our prayer mats for hours,
> asking more and more?  [Shaari Isa; *Release Me Back to the Sea*, Vol 2](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Release_Me_Back_to_the_Sea/Wh3793Og5nAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strive%20wholeheartedly%22&pg=PA119&printsec=frontcover)

> In working with one another to discover and implement a specific
> course of action in coalition, to **strive wholeheartedly** and
> speedily to reach a level of agreement in regard to the action at
> issue. [H. Hay and W. Roscoe; *Radically Gay*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Radically_Gay/ts4xksTvnqcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strive%20wholeheartedly%22&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover)

> That is the end we must now strive for, and it can only be achieved
> if we **strive wholeheartedly** and with clear foresight and
> knowledge.  [H. E. Morgan; "A Nation of Workers" in *The Edinburgh
> Review*, Jan. 1916)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Edinburgh_Review/MZ1HAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strive%20wholeheartedly%22&pg=PA44&printsec=frontcover)

> You should **strive wholeheartedly** for the health of patients. You
> must not harm patients, even for the sake of living. [Dagmar Wujastyk;
> *Well-Mannered Medicine: Medical Ethics and Etiquette in Classical Ayurveda*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Well_Mannered_Medicine/enHkQ8zwLrgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22strive%20wholeheartedly%22&pg=PA89&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

"All in" seems to be the current phrase for describing someone who is fully committed to something. Here is one definition of "all in":

> Putting all of one's available resources into an effort [1](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/all+in)

Exemplar:

> By his obvious lack of enthusiasm, you could tell that Ted was not all in with the the group project.